# Issues with putting two decimal places in float values on python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two float values called payment and interest and I am trying to round them to two decimal places. I am trying to do this using the following code:

```
balance = float("{0:.2f}".format(balance))
interest = float("{0:.2f}".format(interest))
```

However the output is coming in the following way:

```
payment   interest
500.0        54.8
```

Is there any way to format these float values so that the output is:
500.00 and 54.80 instead of 500.0 and 54.8 in python 3? Whenever the second decimal value is a 0 python is not outputting it as a 0. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stop calling `float` on the strings.

Comment: Don’t apply `float` to it. You can’t keep extra 0s behind the decimal, unless it’s stored as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, do the following :

```
balance = "{0:.2f}".format(balance)
interest = "{0:.2f}".format(interest)
```

This will store the result as a `str`.

There is no point in wrapping a `float` around `str` for this purpose since for the sake of computations, the last `0` does not matter